# Exclude certain file extensions from random file selection - batch script

Tags: batch-file, playlist

I'm in the process of making a script that selects 25 random tracks from a user specified folder and adds them into an .m3u playlist. The trouble I have is that my music folders include various other files as well (eg: .txt, .jpg, .png, .nfo, etc...)

So I'm looking for a way of excluding the extensions listed above, limiting the script to just work with audio files. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code so far... It has been stitched together from various sources so accept my apologies if it is a little crude:

```
@echo off
title Multiple Choice Menu
:home
cls
echo.
echo Select a genre:
echo =============
echo.
echo 1) Jungle
echo 2) D'n'B
echo 3) Reggae
echo 4) Hip-Hop
echo 5) Exit
echo.
set /p genre=Type option:
if "%genre%"=="1" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Jungle"
if "%genre%"=="2" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\DnB\Standard DnB"
if "%genre%"=="3" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Reggae
if "%genre%"=="4" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Hip-Hop"
if "%genre%"=="5" exit

:: Clear existing Playlist
@echo. > C:\Users\Brew\Desktop\random.m3u 

:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

:: Open 25 random files
for /l %%N in (1 1 25) do call :openRandomFile

:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"

:openRandomFile
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do (
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set tune=%%B
  @echo !tune! >> C:\Users\Brew\Desktop\random.m3u
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your song's folder is on `%1`.

The `dir` command supports wildcards in the idea that

```
dir *.txt *.xml
```

will only list `.txt` and `.xml` files.

So you can try doing this instead:

```
...
:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
pushd %1
dir /b /s /a-d *.mp3 *.EXT1 *.EXT2 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"
popd
...
```

Where `EXT` will be the extensions you want to match.

This will create your `%tempFile%` with only the files you want. Since the code that selects a file ramdomly works, as I see, over this file, it won't need to change at all.

I couldn't get dir to work with both target directory and wildcards.

Hope it helps.
This is why i used [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [popd](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel,

I had another go at it an finally got something working on my own. I used a series of If statements to put the random file through an extension validation check

This is the working script

```
@echo off
title Multiple Choice Menu
:home
cls
echo.
echo Select a task:
echo =============
echo.
echo 1) Jungle
echo 2) D'n'B
echo 3) Reggae
echo 4) Hip-Hop
echo 5) Exit
echo.
set /p genre=Type option:
if "%genre%"=="1" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Jungle"
if "%genre%"=="2" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\DnB\Standard DnB"
if "%genre%"=="3" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Reggae
if "%genre%"=="4" cd /D "D:\NL Safe 2.0\High Quality\Hip-Hop"
if "%genre%"=="5" exit

:: Clear existing Playlist
@echo. > C:\Users\Brew\Desktop\random.m3u 

:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

:openRandomFile
echo opening random file.....
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do (
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set tune=%%B

FOR %%i IN ("!tune!") do call :CheckifMusic
)


:CheckifMusic
echo checking now
FOR %%i IN ("!tune!") DO (
SET fileextension=%%~xi
IF !fileextension!==.aif goto ResultTrue
IF !fileextension!==.flac goto ResultTrue
IF !fileextension!==.m4a goto ResultTrue
IF !fileextension!==.mp3 goto ResultTrue
IF !fileextension!==.wav goto ResultTrue
IF !fileextension!==.wma goto ResultTrue

echo fail
echo !fileextension!
goto openRandomFile


:ResultTrue
echo pass
echo !fileextension!
@echo !tune! >> C:\Users\Brew\Desktop\random.m3u
set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
IF !COUNTER!==25 (
  echo finished
  pause
  goto Done
) ELSE (
goto openRandomFile
)


:Done
echo.
:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"
exit
)
pause
```

Probably not the cleanest way to do it, but hey - It works!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"
```

with

```
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n /L /E /I /c:".mp3" /c:".wav">"%tempFile%"
```

Where the `/c:".mp3"...` can be extended as many times as you desire to select your target filetypes.

or

with

```
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n /V /L /E /I /c:".jpg" /c:".txt">"%tempFile%"
```

Again repeating the `/c:".jpg"...` as many times as you desire to select your target exclude-me filetypes.

The `/i` means "case-insensitive", `/e` means "at the end of the line" `/L` means "literal match, not regex" and `/v` means "output non-matching"